# Dynamically display row values as columns in HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a query that dynamically displays row values as columns in an HTML table. I can get the query to work in phpMyAdmin. It does exactly what I want, but I don't know how I can present this in an HTML table on my PHP page.

This is the code that works in phpMyAdmin:

```sql
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when field_key = ''',
      field_key,
      ''' then field_value end) ',
      field_key
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  Meeting;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Meeting_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM Meeting 
                   GROUP BY Meeting_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I changed it to this to try to make it work in PHP

```php
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "DB-USER", "DB-PASS", "DB-NAME");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when name = ''',
      name,
      ''' then value end) ',
      name
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  TBL-NAME;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT data_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM TBL-NAME 
                   GROUP BY data_id')"

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {

    /* execute statement */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    /* NO CLUE WHAT TO DO WITH THIS */
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $code);

    /* fetch values */
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
    }

    /* close statement */
    $stmt->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Also tried fiddling arround with some examples I found like below.

```php
if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row. "<br>";
    }
```

Cannot get it to work. Anyone willing to give me some directions?
What I want to achieve is to have user values presented in a table on one line per user.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this is not a discussion forum. Think of SO as Wikipedia. I removed all unrelated information from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql statement must use a multi_Query to work, as it contains multiple queries.

Here is a working example, withoit data, it is difficult to show how it works, but you can change teh datasource in the example and add simply your mysql cpde. to see and experiment with it

```
<?php
$query = "SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
               CONCAT('MAX(IF(s.name = \"', `name`,'\", `value`,\"\")) AS ',name)
              ) INTO @sql
FROM table1;


SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.user_id,  ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM table1 s
                 GROUP BY s.user_id
                 ORDER BY s.user_id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;";
    
    if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* store first result set */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s %s\n", $row[0],$row[1]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* print divider */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}
```

See [example](https://phpize.online/?phpses=5e27ac6e20a87298b5883f875510d754&sqlses=a6b152e81d369df337aca4efa1e2d02c&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: Hi NBK, thank you for your quick reply. That was very helpfull. I just edited your example to show you what I actually want to accomplish with dynamically rows. Now I need to add the correct amount of rows that I need to show. This can be different per form that is being stored in the database. Do you have any idea how I can arrange that?

Comment: you must link the new example else i can't see it but this is a new question, so accept this one and make a new one

Comment: Hi NBK, Thanks again. Just so I understand correctly. I need to close this entire question and open a new question for further fine tuning and details or did you want me to make a new PHPize [example](https://phpize.online/?phpses=9c34701c6edede9f6ac4d0445126ca37&sqlses=b6bec47a5faa956c43c2ed8904ecb926&php_version=php8&sql_version=mariadb)? Sorry, this is a bit new to me.